# Ejecutar parte del código a través de un botón de un formulario y recargar las listas de un combobox

Tags: c#, windows-forms, api, modal

Tengo un formulario donde existe un apartado con un botón "Cargar etiqueta", además hay un comboxbox para seleccionar las etiquetas ya cargadas y botones de cancelar, aceptar y aplicar. Dentro del procedimiento, en primer lugar pincho el botón cargar etiqueta y selecciono la etiqueta que quiero. Hasta ahí todo correcto.

Mi problema es que yo querría que haciendo click en el botón aplicar me cargue la etiqueta en Revit y me actualice la lista del combobox añadiendo esta nueva etiqueta ya cargada.

Es decir, que por un lado, querría que el evento click del botón aplicar, me corra parte del código (el que corresponde a cargar la familia) y además actualice las listas que están vinculadas al combobox.

De momento el formulario es modal, es decir, no ejecuta el código hasta que el formulario no se cierre. Entiendo que para poder ejecutar parte del código el formulario debería ser no modal pero realmente no he trabajado nunca así y no se como hacerlo.

```
public void LanzarFormulario()
    {
        Formulario f = new Formulario();
        f.Show();
    }
```

En el command querria ejecutar la carga de familia al pulsar el botón aplicar

```
//CargarFamilia(documento);
                    Transaction transaccion = new Transaction(documento, "cargar familia");

                    transaccion.Start();

                    Family family;
                    documento.LoadFamily(Formulario.rutafamilia, out family);

                    FamilySymbol fs;
                    FamilySymbolFilter filter = new FamilySymbolFilter(family.Id);
                    FilteredElementCollector colectorFamilia = new FilteredElementCollector(documento);
                    IList<Element> fselements = colectorFamilia.WherePasses(filter).ToElements();

                    //foreach (Element e in fselements)
                    //{
                        //AreaTag area = e as AreaTag;
                        //if (area != null)
                        //{
                            fs = fselements[0] as FamilySymbol;
                            fs.Activate();
                        //}
                        //else
                        //{
                            //message = "No se ha seleccionado ninguna etiqueta de tipo Área.";
                            //return Result.Failed;
                        //}
                    //}

                    transaccion.Commit();
                }
```

Y además saber que tengo que introducir en la clase de l Form en el botón aplicar

```
//Botón Aplicar

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancel = false;
    }
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]!. La verdad, no se si soy yo sólo, pero no termino de entender bien tu pregunta. Tu problema es que el combobox que quieres actualizar está en un formulario diferente a aquel en el que se carga la nueva etiqueta?

Comment: Soy nueva en esto de la programación, así que igual mi pregunta es muy sencilla pero yo no soy capaz de resolverla. El código que tengo ahora mismo es el que esta adjunto. Yo quiero que haciendo click en el botón aplicar (es decir en un botón del formulario) me cargue la familia que he seleccionado (es decir que corra parte del código del command que he adjuntado) y además me actualice el combobox de este mismo formulario añadiéndome esta nueva familia que he cargado. No se si esto contesta a tu pregunta. Muchas gracias

Comment: Yo utilizo uno o varios PlaceHolder en la página y desde su página secundaria de código creo un LiteralControl que me reescribe el formulario tal y como me interesa. Por lo tanto, cuando se pulsa el botón, manda de nuevo la petición, recoge o no datos de una base de datos por ejemplo y me trae el formulario con los campos rellenos o con más o menos campos. Si solo quiero enviar medio formulario utilizo un UpdatePanel